# Plotly and altair

Tags: python, visualization

I have a question about these two bookstores: Plotly and Altair. They are both used for data visualization and interaction. However, when I use them with a 300,000 line dataset, my notebook doesn't seem to hold up. Can someone please explain to me why and if this is normal? Thank you